# Import data failed using sunspot and postgres on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot, rails-postgresql, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

I wrote a rake file to import auto-generated items to my database.

When I delete all and then redo the import,

the development log as following

```
 7 Connecting to database specified by database.yml
  8    (0.5ms)  BEGIN
  9   Book Exists (1.1ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "books" WHERE "books"."sn" = 2123000001 LIMIT 1
```

and when I use rails console or rails db to look up the table "Book"

the table is empty , because I executed the delete_all()

So, I have no idea why I re-import the  data and tell me the data has existed.

I've tried to look up my database via RAILS_ENV=production and RAILS_ENV=development.

there is nothing in my production DB because I haven't run on production mode

Any ideas?

```
rake aborted!
RSolr::Error::Http - 500 Internal Server Error
Error:     Severe errors in solr configuration.

Check your log files for more detailed information on what may be wrong.

If you want solr to continue after configuration errors, change:

 <abortOnConfigurationError>false</abortOnConfigurationError>

in solr.xml

-------------------------------------------------------------

Request Data: "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><add><doc><field name=\"id\">Book 431</field><field name=\"type\">Book</field><field name=\"type\">ActiveRecord::Base</field><field name=\"class_name\">Book</field><field name=\"name_text\">剩食</field><field name=\"author_text\">陳曉蕾著</field><field name=\"comment_text\">在消費主義盛行的年代，如何跳脫買得越多、剩得越多、對環境破壞越多的惡性循環？本書憑藉豐富數據、照片與精闢的分析，讓讀者自然而然願意開始「三思而後食」。（黃宗慧）</field><field name=\"sale_type_text\">normal</field><field name=\"category_text\">體育</field></doc></add>"
```

Environment

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27 revision 41675) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]

sunspot (2.0.0)
sunspot_rails (2.0.0)
sunspot_solr (2.0.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

probably rake open other environment. try something like:

```
rake RAILS_ENV=developmant your_generator
```

when you open console you can see which env it opened

Comment: Not worked. because I've never run on production mode. the table in production is NULL

Comment: do you check test env also?